# Unknown compiler option 'files' launching ./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface

In order to translate my angular 4 app I'm trying to launch

> ./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n
>    from the root directory but I'm facing a problem and here is my log :

```
    Error: Error Unknown compiler option 'files'.
    at UserError.Error (native)
    at new UserError (/Users/danilodughetti/Coding/creatiweapp/creatiwe/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:27:28)
    at check (/Users/danilodughetti/Coding/creatiweapp/creatiwe/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:93:15)
    at Tsc.readConfiguration (/Users/danilodughetti/Coding/creatiweapp/creatiwe/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:152:9)
    at Object.main (/Users/danilodughetti/Coding/creatiweapp/creatiwe/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:65:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/danilodughetti/Coding/creatiweapp/creatiwe/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/extract_i18n.js:16:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
Extraction failed
```

my package.js is like this :

> "name": "eheheh",
>         "version": "0.0.0",
>         "license": "MIT",
>         "scripts": {
>           "ng": "ng",
>           "start": "ng serve",
>           "build": "ng build",
>           "test": "ng test",
>           "lint": "ng lint",
>           "e2e": "ng e2e"
>         },
>         "private": true,
>         "dependencies": {
>           "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
>           "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
>           "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
>           "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
>           "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
>           "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
>           "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
>           "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
>           "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
>           "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
>           "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
>           "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
>           "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
>           "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
>           "core-js": "^2.4.1",
>           "firebase": "^4.4.0",
>           "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
>           "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
>           "ng2-markdown-to-html": "^1.3.2",
>           "ng2wig": "^0.2.1",
>           "ngx-loading": "^1.0.7",
>           "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
>           "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
>         },
>         "devDependencies": {
>           "@angular/cli": "1.4.3",
>           "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
>           "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
>           "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
>           "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
>           "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
>           "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
>           "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
>           "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
>           "karma": "~1.7.0",
>           "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
>           "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
>           "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
>           "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
>           "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
>           "protractor": "~5.1.2",
>           "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
>           "tslint": "~5.3.2",
>           "typescript": "~2.3.3"
>         }
>       }

Thanks

Comment: check your `tsconfig.json`. It is probably invalid (having `files` under `compileOptions`)

Comment: Thanks. It solved!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you see `Error Unknown compiler option 'files'` for TypeScript project, it is most likely that your `tsconfig.json` is incorrect.

You probably have:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "files": [ ... ]
  }
}
```

Rather than:

```
/// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "files": [ ... ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already solved with include and exclude tag but the answer is correct bye!

Comment: You saved me. Thanks!